# Microsoft Action Pack - what software is included?

Tags: sql-server, actionpack

I am thinking to join MS Action pack subscription.

Does anyone have a list of the exact software I can use?

I am very interested in MSSQL 2012/2014 as I have a dual quad core machine (8 cores) and wanted to know if I can run MSSQL 2012 or 2014 on it with my Action Pack License.

Answer (score 2):

Shame Microsoft can't make this information easily discoverable on their website. Here is a link which I eventually found with Google, which will probably break within 2 months, because that's how Microsoft roll....

https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/downloads/software-licensing-for-action-pack-subscription-partners.aspx (seems to be dated 2014, PDF main points copied below)

```
Windows 10 Enterprise (Current Branch or 2015 Long Term Service Branch) (Upgrade Only)
Microsoft Desktop Optimization Pack 2015
Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Pro
Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry Enterprise
Windows Embedded 8 Standard
Windows Embedded 7 Standard
Windows Embedded POS Ready 7
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 Standard
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 client access licenses (CALs)
Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
Windows Server 2012 CALs (not edition specific)
Windows Server 2012 Remote Desktop Services (RDS) CALs
Windows MultiPoint Server 2012 CALs
Windows MultiPoint Server 2012 Premium
Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials
Windows Server 2012 R2 Foundation
Windows Storage Server 2012 R2 Workgroup
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
Microsoft Project Professional 2013
Microsoft Visio Professional 2013
Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 Standard
Skype for Business Server 2015
Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Workgroup Server 2015
Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Standard
Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Client Management Suite Client MLs
Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Configuration Manager Client MLs
Microsoft System Center 2012 R2 Endpoint Protection
3 Visual Studio Professional licenses
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the Action Pack you have to become a Microsoft Partner. Then there are two packs. The developer pack definitely includes SQL Server.

Dig around on the [Partner web site](https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/uk/Pages/index.aspx) and you should find the details.

Comment: There were, but there aren't any more

Comment: yeah, I tried digging around but the information is vague at best. in fact today that link to partner site gives the error "An unexpected error has occurred.".

Comment: OK, I found https://partner.microsoft.com/download/40196872 on https://mspartner.microsoft.com/en/us/pages/membership/action-pack-software-licensing-benefits-faq.aspx#Benefits - it might answer your questions. I will say that when I had this subscription I found the partner web site to be pretty bad...

Comment: Hmmm, I just bought MICROSOFT SQL Server Developer Edition 2012 from amazon as its apparently the full version but for dev environment. Will be here tomorrow!

:o)

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that was available! Looks like good value, too.